# How to get_text() in all tags but without some special tags in BeautifulSoup (Python)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, tags, gettext, except

so I have example

```
<body>
<div>I have a code 
    <img href"http://....jpg" />
    <p>title image</p>
    this so cool
</div>
</body>
```

then I want OUTput look like:

```
    I have a code 
    <img href"http://....jpg" />
    title image
    this so cool
```

so thanks for help

Comment: `<img href"http://....jpg" />` isn't text. SO you can't get them using `get_text()`.

Comment: yep, thanks bro, so can you help me

Comment: What help do you need ?

Comment: can you give some solution in example above, thanks

Comment: You need everything inside `div` tag ?

Comment: yes bro, all text but keep img tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.contents` that returns a list of the contents of the `div`. Then you handle accordingly the result.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")    
soup.find("div").contents
```